# What is the difference between \PassOptionsToPackage and inline options passing?

Tags: classicthesis, package-options

I have noticed that, for example, ClassicThesis config file uses this style:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}.
```

What is the difference between these two options of passing the options to a package? In other words, what is the goal of supporting both types of syntax for arguments in TeX (or LaTeX?)?

Comment: `classicthesis` has some *interesting features*. You have more characters to tyoe in.

Comment: I don't really know why the author of `classicthesis` does like that. There is no point in doing so.

Comment: I'll explain: it's because of its use with LyX: when LyX calls its packages, it passes them options inline. When classicthesis then calls the same packages, LaTeX reports option clashes, and, I believe, stops compiling. This seemed like the easiest way out of the situation. Call it the price of technological progress :)

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Preventing option clashes. You are the `classicthesis` expert, please provide the answert :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B  ?!??

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Don't just comment, write up an answer. I will even upvote it :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I hoped a LaTeX expert would provide a better solution for option clashes when classicthesis and LyX, the two he truly dislikes, are used together :-)

Comment: ClassicThesis is just an illustration. Why do these two types of syntax exist in TeX? Obviously, it was not introduced to make LyX work. I've updated the question.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Either you know what you are loading and why, or you confuse LaTeX by doing otherwise and get the option clash. It is like demanding to put on green socks and later demanding to put on red socks, there is a collision. Option passing is kind of the smooth way  to prevent this, keeping in mind that someone probably wants to wear blue socks in the future.

Comment: There is TeX at the core, next comes LaTeX, beyond that, there is LyX, trying to give you an interface to simple text, which hides the text. I do not use LyX. It hides the text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

foo

\end{document}
```

gives an `option clash`, because a package can be loaded only one time! And that is done for `hyperref` by `beamer` itself internally, but without an optional argument. LaTeX marks `hyperref` as loaded after the first `usepackage` or `RequirePackage` and then throughs an error if a package should be loaded a second time with *different* optional arguments. In such a case a `\PassOptionsToPackage` helps, or only for beamer one can use `hyperref=colorlinks`:

```
 \documentclass[xcolor=table,hyperref=colorlinks,...]{beamer}
 \begin{document}

 foo

 \end{document}
```

A user often didn't  know what packages are already loaded by the documentclass or other packages or by LyX in its defined preamble. Then he/she realizes only by the option-clash error that a package should be loaded more than once.

Comment: In short, to pass argument to a package that already has been declared?

Comment: Not really: `\PassOptionsToPackage` has to be used _before_ the package will be loaded. The reason why it is often used before `\documentclass`.